# What is Cin and Cout in this design?

Tags: charge, controller

I am trying to build my first circuit which is a simple battery charger:

[image: simple solar battery charger]

I found the first components I need ( diode, fuse and regulator) but I don't understand what Cout and Cin are in this picture.

Are those components to buy? Or is it just representing the current in and the current out?

Thanks a lot,

Adrien

Comment: They're capacitors

Comment: Just google "33uF, 25V" and look at the images: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=33uF,+25V&espv=2&biw=1235&bih=914&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6gJySwJvQAhUGXBoKHYm9CCwQ_AUIBygC. VTC

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown zero levels of research.

Comment: Sorry for this. I did research for Cin and Cout but all I could find was C++ related topics. Thanks for your time Andy aka and @Hayman

Comment: Cin and Cout are designations for Input Capacitor and Output Capacitor. If you want to get into circuit design it might be a good idea to learn what most of the circuit symbols looks like. http://zrat.net/uploads/symbols.jpg

Comment: Find and study the datasheet for the linear regulator - it should discuss the need for, and recommended values of, the input and output capacitors.

Answer (score 1):

Cin and Cout are capacitors. The schematic suggests they are polarized (+ sign on top). According to their values, you should use Electrolytic or Tantalum capacitors. Make sure your actual capacitors are connected the right way, or they will be damaged and possibly damage other components in the circuit.

The values you have to look for are 33µF for Cin, and 56µF for Cout. The voltage values are the voltage they have to be rated for. In your actual circuit, you can use components rated for these exact voltages or higher, but I would not recommend to use capacitors with lower rated voltages.

Comment: @Hayman: why is it possibly going to damage other components than the capacitors? Is it because it can turn to a short-circuit?